# Getting `Invalid API or resource` while calling `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe` for Onedrive

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to call `GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe` via postman with appropriate headers Headers, but getting following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid API or resource"
    }
}
```

Referring [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_sharedwithme?view=odsp-graph-online)

My aim is to be able to see any files or folders shared with me, via above call.
Also, kindly provide suggestion for the ability to download files that are shared with me.

[postmanAPICall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jKPG.png)

I would like to know if my API call is correct or am I missing anything. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: When people help you voluntarily, you really shouldn't say "ASAP". Most likely it will just have negative impact.

Comment: Thanks guys. Duly noted.